# gdb cout a double close to 0

Tags: c++, gdb, cout

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define SIZE_LETTERS (254)

using namespace std;

void analyzeF(const string *input, char a, int *freq) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (input)->length(); ++i) {
            if ((*input)[i] == a)
                    ++(*freq);      
    }
}

int main() {
    int freq = 0;

    string input = "53\u2021\u2021\u2020305))6*;4826)4\u2021.)4\u2021);806*;48\u2020860))85;;]8*;:\u2021*8\u202083(88)5*\u2020;46(;88*96*?;8)*\u2021(;485);5*\u20202:*\u2021(;4956*2(5*\u20144)88*;4069285);)6\u20208)4\u2021\u2021;1(\u20219;48081;8:8\u20211;48\u202085;4)485\u2020528806*81(\u20219;48;(88;4(\u2021?34;48)4\u2021;161;:188;\u2021?;";
    char c;

    cout << "Please enter a character to be matched: " << endl;
    cin >> c;
    analyzeF(&input, c, &freq);

    double result = (double)freq/SIZE_LETTERS;
    cout << "The frequency for " << c << " is:" << result << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

This program is written to detect the frequency of a char that is used in the string.

When I execute the program, whatever I type for char c, The output value is 0.

However, when I debug it in gdb, it gives out the correct result. for example the frequency for 8 is 0.133858.

The command that I use to generate the .o object is:

```
g++ -g c.cpp -o c
./c
```

Comment: Works here: `The frequency for 8 is:0.133858`.

Comment: The compiler command you showed is missing the `-o`; it should be `g++ -g c.cpp -o c`

Comment: The frequency of the letter is `(double)freq/input.length()`, too.

Comment: Some comments on the code: avoid macros and defines, prefer a constant to a define for `SIZE_LETTERS`, avoid constants when you can, remove `SIZE_LETTERS` altogether and use `input.size()`. Use *references* when you can to simplify the code (i.e. `analyzeF` can be implemented with references and dropping a few `*` from the code). A common convention for successful execution of a program is returning 0 from `main` (it is optional, if you don't return there will be an implicit `return 0;` at the end of the function).

Comment: If you haven't learned about passing arguments to functions as references, I think it's time now.